# Get many to many fields changes in a post save in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-signals

So, I have a `post_save` signal in my code to save logs of changes in models, but the changes in many to many fields aren't applied at the point `post_save` is triggered, so changes in m2m fields aren't saved in my logs.

My code (you can pretty much ignore the code inside the method):

```
def save_log(sender, instance, created, raw, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if (
        not hasattr(sender, '_meta') or
        sender._meta.label not in settings.MODELS_TO_BE_LOGGED
    ):
        return

    sensitive_fields = ['password', ]

    user = get_user()

    # This creates the log with a json describing the changes
    if created:
        # This method creates a log
        instance.save_addition(user, '')
    else:
        changed_field_labels = {}
        original_dict = instance.original_dict
        actual_dict = instance.to_dict(
            exclude=['created_at', 'updated_at', 'original_dict', 'id'],
        )

        change = False
        for key in set(list(actual_dict.keys()) + list(original_dict.keys())):
            if original_dict.get(key) != actual_dict.get(key):
                change = True
                if key == sensitive_fields:
                    changed_field_labels[key] = {'change': 'field updated'}
                else:
                    changed_field_labels[key] = {
                        'from': original_dict.get(key, '-'),
                        'to': actual_dict.get(key, '-'),
                    }

        if change:
            json_message = json.dumps(
                {'changed': {'fields': changed_field_labels}},
                cls=ModelEncoder
            )
            # This method creates a log
            instance.save_edition(user, json_message)
```

For example, consider a model `Event` that has a many to many field to `EventCategory` called `categories`. If changes were made to an event through an UpdateView, for example (including changes to `categories`), and the method is called, if I do `event.categories.all()`, it will show the previous categories, without the changes.

I can use the `m2m_changed` signal to save logs, but it will create separate logs, and for example if someone changed the categories from [A, B, C] to [A, B, D], it will trigger two times, one for removing C, and other for removing D, resulting in a lot of logs. I can do stuff like group logs based on the user and the log creation time (if the logs were created within 1 second I can merge them or something).

Is there something I can do to get the changes inside the method with the `post_save` hook?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use `m2m_changed` and update the just saved log with the m2m info?

Comment: Yeah, but how can I get the log? I guess I can search all the logs for the object, made by the user, and created within a second, and update that log, but it's not an ideal solution in my opinion. I'm using the Django LogEntry model btw.